# How to fix 'list index out of range' error in ZigZag problem?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

I have a list index out of range error on Line 6 upon using a list of list approach to solve the ZigZag problem (https://leetcode.com/problems/zigzag-conversion/). Why is there such an error?

```
def convert(self, s, numRows):
        row=0
        down=True
        rows=[[] for i in range(numRows)]
        for i in range(len(s)):
            rows[row].extend(s[i])
            #print(rows)
            if(row==0):
                down=True
            elif(row==len(s)-1):
                down=False
            if down:
                row+=1
            else:
                row-=1
        st=[]
        for k in rows:
            st+=k
        return ''.join(st)
```

Comment: Do you understand the error message?

Comment: @Blorgbeard I believe so. The rows array is being accessed beyond its initial setup. But 'row' is incremented/ decremented to take care of that. Am I right?

Comment: The initial capacity of `rows` is `numrows`, which doesn't seem related to `len(s)` in any way, so why would you expect `rows[row]` to stay within bounds?

Comment: `elif(row==len(s)-1)` - should that not be `len(rows)`?

Comment: Your `row` goes out of bounds, the reason for that you use `len(s)` (with `s`) instead of `numRows`. But nevertheless it is still incorrect.

Comment: ```elif(row==numRows-1):```  that fixes it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to the fact that you compare `(row==len(s)-1)`. Now `s` is the string, not the number of rows, so for a string that is larger than the number of rows, eventually `row` will be that large that it goes out of bounds.

That being said, we can improve the code effectively. We know that the row *r<sub>i</sub>* on which we assign the *i*-th element is a sequence *0, 1, ..., n-1, n-2, ..., 0, 1, ...*. So we can define a function for this like:

```
def pingpong(n):
    while True:
        yield from range(n)
        yield from range(n-2, 0, -1)
```

For example:

```
>>> list(islice(pingpong(3), 14))
[0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1]
>>> list(islice(pingpong(4), 14))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1]
```

Then we can thus append each row of the `pingpong` function with the corresponding character:

```
def zigzag(text, numRows):
    rows = [[] for _ in range(numRows)]
    for ri, c in zip(pingpong(numRows), text):
        rows[ri].append(c)
    return ''.join(map(''.join, rows))
```

Which gives us:

```
>>> zigzag('PAYPALISHIRING', 3)
'PAHNAPLSIIGYIR'
>>> zigzag('PAYPALISHIRING', 4)
'PINALSIGYAHRPI'
```

I submitted the above approach to the LeetCode puzzle, and it got accepted (all test cases succeeded).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is solved when the '`row`' parameter is updated with '`numRows`' instead of with `len(s)`. The row parameter determines whether the direction of travel is up or down and upon correctly updating the limit cases of '`row`', the out of bounds error disappears.